# Handle the safe area in Chrome browser on the iPhone X family

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, frontend, iphone-x

For the website that I am managing, I am handling the iPhone X family screen safe area using the new `safe-area-inset-<position>` and this is working fine on Safari browser as you can see here:

[image: handling safe area on safari]

With the following code:

```
/* white container for the home bar that has an height only on devices that read the safe area to cover the transparency around that bar */
.ctc-container {
    background: $white;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
    z-index: 100;
}

/* chat and phone number container are positioned at the bottom of the safe area (for devices that read it) or at the bottom of the page */
.ctc-box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
}
```

Now the problem is on Chrome browser because apparently it is not handling the safe area yet, so the chat and phone number box is overlapped by the iPhone home bar.

[image]

Is there any CSS solution that can be applied for Chrome on iPhone X family devices to handle the safe area?

Comment: Chrome iOS still uses the *Safari* rendering engine...

Comment: Apparently this is not true https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/350674/297267. In any case I do not get this comment...

Comment: Read that link again. "all Chrome variants **except iOS**" - just like I said.

Comment: Ok, so why it is not working? I do not get your initial comment

Comment: Did you find solution for this ? i have same problem

Comment: @walee the approved answeris the solution for this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added `viewport-fit=cover` to your `meta[name="viewport"]`?